# Is it possible to use Core Data in iCloud as server, and the iPad's as clients?

Tags: ios, core-data, client-server, icloud

We are using a server-client architecture. All the iPad-s are synchronizing back data through web service to MSSQL database.

What do you think does it make sense to save in Core Data that is stored in iCloud rather then MSSQL?!

Is it possible to use Core Data as server, and the iPad-s as clients?

How can I develop client-server platform using only Apple technologies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to use iCloud as a "server-side" **data storage** for your CoreData application but there seem to be a lot of issues with CoreData+iCloud so it looks like it's not yet completely ready for production use. I hope iOS6 will make it more usable.

You can read a bit more here - [Questions concerning iCloud + core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959357/questions-concerning-icloud-core-data)

I also suggest you reading this thread on Apple Dev's forum - https://devforums.apple.com/thread/126670?tstart=0 (Must be registered developer to view this)